# Accidentally Changed name of linux.so in lib64 folder

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, bin

[image]

I happen to accidentally change name of linux-ld32.so in lib64 folder to something, now nothing seems to be working. As uploaded in the image above, whichever icons i click upon, nothing opens up.

Please help as I have many important files in my system.

Comment: Which command used to change the name of your file? `cp ??` , `mv` ? are you able to switch to the console through ctrl + alt + F3  before loging into the GUI?

Comment: MV command. Now pressed ctrl+alt+f3 , screen is blank

Comment: Switch to the TTY before loging

Comment: How to switch to TTY? As I have only blank screen and system is irresponsive

Comment: Reboot your system when the connexion window appear Press Ctrl + ALT + F2 , or F3... type your login Press Enter then your password , type history the see the last executed command , then rename your file

Comment: You are renamed a symlink not the original file , use `mv` command and set the exact name

Comment: Man, I'm pressing ctrl alt f2 , system screen is blank, while Ubuntu boot. Please help